# how to display a horizontal scroll bar on a website

Tags: html, css

i want to display a horizontal scroll bar when my website is minimized and to hide it when in full window. please help. Dennis

Comment: Show me what code you tried???

Comment: style="overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll"

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
body {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in style.css

```
 body
    {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a value of 'scroll' will always show the scrollbar, no matter whether it's needed. On Windows in Firefox at least.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried this:-

```
style="overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll
```

Go to this Url will be helpful for you :-
http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/horizontal_scroll.cfm

Try to run this code:-

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;">
<p style="width:250%;">
By using overflow-x, we can create scroll bars when the contents of this div are wider than the container. By setting this paragraph to 250 percent, it is 250 percent wider than the parent container - forcing an overflow. 
</p>
</div>
<p style="font-size:10px;"><a href="#">Create blog</a></p>
```